# How to use ajax with prototype and jsps

Tags: ajax, forms, jsp, prototypejs

I'm developing social faq solution.

When I click on vote up or vote down, i want to make an ajax call to a java function.

I've worked with struts on another project, and i was making call to struts action.

Now I work only with simple jsp, servlets ... and I dont know how to make an ajax call to a java function which will send me json or xml.

Answer (score 0):

- [Prototype Ajax Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/prototype/prototype_ajax_tutorial.htm)
- [Ajax for Java](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-ajax2/)

Comment: I dont know which url should i call : new Ajax.Request('/some_url',

In struts i was able to call directly struts action